# Add Browserify to existing Gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I created the following Gulp task:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var gulputil    = require('gulp-util');
var gulpif      = require('gulp-if');
var sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify      = require('gulp-uglify');

var scriptInput = './resources/assets/scripts/*.js';

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var production = gulputil.env.production ? true : false;
    return gulp.src(scriptInput)
        .pipe(gulpif(!production, sourcemaps.init()))
        .pipe(gulpif(!production, sourcemaps.write()))
        .pipe(gulpif(production, uglify(options.uglify)))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptOutput))
        .on('error', gulputil.log);
});
```

This task takes all the scripts in my script directory and compiles them. Depending on whether I passed a production flag to my gulp command, it will generate sourcemaps or uglify the resulting script. So far so good.

There's one thing missing in my task though, which is Browserify. I'm still quite a novice at Gulp and I can't wrap my head around how to incorporate this into my existing task. I've seen a couple examples on how to do this (many using the blacklisted `gulp-browserify` package) but these look way more complicated and very different from the task I'm using. Another limitation in these examples is that they don't seem to support using a wildcard path like I'm using (see variable `scriptInput` in the example).

My question is: is there an easy way to add Browserify to this task without losing the functionality of the original task, especially the ability to use a wildcard source path?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include `browserify` , then you would use it as below like in my below example , where am transforming vue file using vuiefy , Yes you can see i have also required `fs`

```
 ...(some more require here )
var fs = require("fs");
var browserify = require('browserify');
 var vueify = require('vueify');
// Compile Our Vue js
gulp.task('vueify', function() {
   return  browserify(srcpath +'js/app.js')
  .transform(vueify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destpath +"js/build.js"))

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not seem to work with my original question. ("My question is: is there an easy way to add Browserify to this task without losing the functionality of the original task, especially the ability to use a wildcard source path?")